# How to save a string variable from views in Django

Tags: python, django, ocr

I'm trying to use pytesseract for my Django application. In views.py I called pytesseract and stored all the text it found in the 'text_content' variable. I want to save this variable as the 'text' parameter for my model, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I tried to use .save(), but got this error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'save'

Here is views.py

```
def image_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = partForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data = request.POST.copy() 
            image_file = request.FILES.get('image')
            text_content = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_file))
            text_content.save()
            return redirect('success')
    else:
        form = partForm()
    return render(request, 'add_image.html', {'form' : form})
```

Here is models.py

```
class Component(models.Model):
    snum = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = '')
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(default = 'no text found')
```

Here is forms.py

```
class partForm(forms.ModelForm):
    snum = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="please enter the 
    number.")

   class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = ['snum', 'image']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occuring because of this line. `text_content.save()`

You're trying to call save function on a string object.

Now to solve your problem, there are two ways to do it. One is to manipulate the request data and send it to the form, other is to do in the save method of your model.

Way 1: in your current view

```
if form.is_valid():
    data = request.POST.copy()
    image_file = request.FILES.get('image')
    text_content = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_file))
    data['relevant_field_name'] = text_content
    new_form = partForm(data) 
    if new_form.is_valid():
        new_form.save() 
return redirect('success')
```

Way 2: in models.py, add this to Component

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if getattr(self, 'image'): 
          image_file = self.image
          self.relevant_field_name = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_file))
    super(Component, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I tried the first method and it works now! Thanks so much!!